# Capybara/Selenium unable to connect to phantomjs on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, capybara

I am using Cucumber and Selenium. In my env.rb, I am registering the phantomjs driver as follows:

```
Capybara.register_driver :phantomjs do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
  caps['acceptSslCerts']=true
  caps['javascriptEnabled']=true
  caps['webStorageEnabled']=true
  caps['applicationCacheEnabled']=true
  caps['nativeEvents']=true
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => caps)
end
```

This driver is set as default driver as follows:

```
Before do  
  Capybara.app_host = "www.google.com"
  Capybara.current_driver = :phantomjs
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :phantomjs
end
```

This works fine on Mac and the test is passing. But on ubuntu I get this error

```
Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1 port 8910 Errno:ECONNREFUSED
```

I checked using netstat and I see that phantomjs is running.
I am on Ubuntu 15.04. I see the same problem in 14.04

Comment: I think, You should use `.quit` method in the end of the script at first, and second - kill this processes before starting your script. Cause phantomjs is still work even if your script is finished

Comment: I did a ps -ef | grep phantomjs to check if phantomjs is running, its not running when the script is not running. It runs when the script runs and when I terminate the script, the phantomjs process is also terminating.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are facing this error everytime, then you need to update Selenium Standalone server.

if you are facing this issue intermittently, then you can try with restarting phantomjs also

```
def restart_phantomjs
        puts "-> Restarting phantomjs: iterating through capybara sessions..."
        session_pool = Capybara.send('session_pool')
        session_pool.each do |mode,session|
          msg = "  => #{mode} -- "
          driver = session.driver
          if driver.is_a?(Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver)
            msg += "restarting"
            driver.restart
          else
            msg += "not poltergeist: #{driver.class}"
          end
          puts msg
        end
      end
      module_function :restart_phantomjs
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

It installs 1.9 version by default.
I installed the latest version 2.1.1 and it worked fine.